# Necessary and sufficient conditions for invertibility of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, finite-element-method

Given $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $B_0,B_1\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$, let us consider the block matrix:
$$
M=
\begin{pmatrix}
A &B_1^T \\
B_0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
arising in the discretisation of some generalise saddle point problems.
I am looking for necessary and sufficient conditions on $A,B_0,B_1$ guaranteeing the invertibility of the matrix $M$. Any ideas?

Moreover I am wondering if there is a flaw in the following reasoning, providing sufficient conditions.

1. $\ker B_1^T =\{ 0\}$
2. $A|_{\ker B_1}\to \ker B_0$ is injective.

Assume indeed that 1. and 2. hold. Let us consider $\left(u,p\right)\in \mathbb R^{n}\times \mathbb R^m$ such that
\begin{equation}\label{eq:matrix_weak_pb_fe_hom}
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B_1^T \\
B_0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u \\
p
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
First of all, we observe that the second equation implies $u\in \ker B_0$. By projecting, via the orthogonal projection $\pi_{K_1}:\mathbb R^n\to \ker B_1$, the first ''block equation'' of the linear system onto $\ker B_1$ and using $\ker B_1 \cong \left(\operatorname{Im} B_1^T\right)^\perp$, we get $\pi_{K_1}A u =0$. Thanks to 1., we conclude $u=0$. Hence, the first ''block equation'' of the linear system implies $B_1^Tp=0$, from which we deduce $p=0$ by using the injectivity of $B_1^T$.

Comment: In 2., why is $A|_{\ker B_1}$ mapping to $\ker B_0$?

Comment: @Berci Because when I project $Au$ to $\ker B_1$ I need to conclude $u=0$. On the other hand we have $u\in \ker B_0$.

Comment: @avati91  Here is a trivial case: $m=n$ and $M$ is invertible, iff, $B_0$ and $B_1^T$ are both invertible. So one may assume $n > m$. On the other hand, if $n > m$ and $A$ is invertible, then $M$ is invertible, iff, $B_0$ and $B_1^T$ are both full rank. Summarily, one may assume that $n > m$ and $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: @RiverLi I do not want to assume $A$ is invertible.

Comment: @avati91 That's what I mean, to exclude the trivial cases.

Comment: @RiverLi thanks for the clarification

Comment: @avati91  So, a related problem is: Assume that $n > m$, $B$ and $C$ are full rank,  and $A$ is singular. Discuss the conditions under which $M$ is invertible. A special case is discuss in https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82294936.pdf